# Take ratio of the mean of two groups for all numeric variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr to divide the mean of all numeric variables for one group by the mean of another group. My data has only two groups. I can do it but the last line I need to manually list each variable name.  I'm wondering if there is an easier way where I just divide all the means for the "Pos" grou by all the means for the "Neg" group without having to manually indicate the column name.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
dt_ex = data.table(group_name = rep(c("Pos", "Neg"), each = 5),
                   random_cat_variable = rep(c("a", "b","c","d", "e"), each = 2),
                   "num_var_1" = rnorm(10), "num_var_2" = rnorm(10), 
                   "num_var_3" = rnorm(10))

mean_DT = dt_ex %>% group_by(group_name) %>% summarize_if(is.numeric, mean)

ratio_vars = mean_DT %>%  mutate(num_var_1_ratio = num_var_1[2] / num_var_1[1],
         num_var_2_ratio = num_var_2[2] / num_var_2[1], 
         num_var_3_ratio = num_var_3[2] / num_var_3[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
mean_DT %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('num'), ~ .x[2]/.x[1], .names = "{.col}_ratio"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  group_name num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_1_ratio num_var_2_ratio num_var_3_ratio
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Neg          -0.0443     0.109    -0.116           -4.37            2.82            6.32
2 Pos           0.194      0.308    -0.733           -4.37            2.82            6.32
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
mean_DT[paste0(names(mean_DT)[-1], "_ratio")] <- as.list(mean_DT[2,-1]/mean_DT[1,-1])
```